# Inverting Colors Inside a Material (UE4)?

Tags: colors, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm attempting to write a material that will invert any color inside it, but I'm not sure where to start. For instance, half of that red cube should be inverted to blue once it enters the space of the material. I would assume it has something to do with modulating (blend type)? If anyone could give any assistance, I would be appreciative.
[What I Have So Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hQ4Tc.jpg)

Comment: Your question isn't precise enough to answer. What does "invert a color" mean? Are you asking about how to implement the math to "invert" the color or are you asking how to make the color invert when it enters some space?

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll need some blending but it's the same as using a PostProcess material as a filter inside a PostProcess volume. That way you create a way to manipulate buffers as a postprocess effect.

Material-wise, inverting the colors (which I'm assuming it means using the opposite color in the spectrum) simply feed the color to a 1-X material node and pass on the result.